Difference between createEmbeddedView and insert method of ViewContainerRef in Angular
when using ViewContainerRef to insert new View the two method createEmbeddedView and insert work differently. I have two ng-container: #vc1 and #vc2.
The createEmbeddedView method insert the template in both container but insert method just add one, but when i reinitialize the view below is the output
this.vcr1.insert(view)
view = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null) //reinitialize
this.vcr2.insert(view)

//Output
//I am span in template I am span in template
<ng-container #vc1>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #tpl>
  <span>I am span in template  </span>
</ng-template>

<ng-container #vc2>
</ng-container>
<button (click)="addView()">Add new view</button>

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('tpl') tpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
    @ViewChild('vc1', {read:ViewContainerRef}) vcr1!:ViewContainrRef
    @ViewChild('vc2',{read:ViewContainerRef}) vcr2!:ViewContainerRef

addView(){
    let view = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null)
    this.vcr1.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl)
    this.vcr2.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl)
    //Output 
    //I am span in template I am span in template

   //this.vcr1.insert(view)
   //this.vcr2.insert(view)
   //Output
   //I am span in template 
}

}

An EmbeddedViewRef can only be inserted into one ViewContainerRef at a time, because the EmbeddedViewRef also contains the actual HTML Elements that are created from the Template.
In your commented out code, your are creating one view. When you call this.vcr2.insert(view), it will move the EmbeddedViewRef from vcr1 to vcr2 along with the HTML Elements.
In your uncommented code, you are creating three views each with their own Elements. The two that are created from vcr.createEmbeddedview are automatically attached to the ViewContainerRefs and the one created from tpl.createEmbeddedView is not attached anywhere.
If you want to display the template multiple times, you also need to create multiple views.
